Bash variable in JMESPath query expression
I have such a code:
# Extract zones
$Zones = az network private-dns zone list -g "rg-test-westeurope" --query '[].{Name: name}' --output json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Initialize an empty array to store record sets
$RecordSets = @()

# Iterate over each zone
foreach ($zone in $Zones) {
     $zone.Name
    # List record sets for the current zone and append to the array
    $RecordSets += az network private-dns record-set a list -g "rg-test-westeurope" -z $zone.Name --query '[].{Zone:$zone.Name, IPv4: aRecords[0].ipv4Address, Name: name}' --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
}

but this part doesnt work for me: Zone:$zone.Name
How can I integrate $zone.Name in my query to have such result
# Convert the array of record sets into a table
$RecordSets | Format-Table -Property Zone, IPv4, Name


This happens because you are in a single quoted string and bash does not expands variable in those, use double quoted ones.


--query "[].{Zone:$zone.Name, IPv4: aRecords[0].ipv4Address, Name: name}"


Thank you for your hint. If I put it in ' then it works: "[].{Zone:'$zone.Name', IPv4: aRecords[0].ipv4Address, Name: name}"but I get such an output which is not what I expect: @{Name=westeurope.datafactory.azure.net}.Name I need only this part: westeurope.datafactory.azure.net

Initially, I too got similar response when I ran this PowerShell script to list record sets with their DNS zone names:
# Extract zones
$Zones = az network private-dns zone list -g "rgName" --query '[].{Name: name}' --output json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Initialize an empty array to store record sets
$RecordSets = @()

# Iterate over each zone
foreach ($zone in $Zones) {
     $zone.Name
    # List record sets for the current zone and append to the array
    $RecordSets += az network private-dns record-set a list -g "rgName" -z $zone.Name --query "[].{Zone:'$zone.Name', IPv4: aRecords[0].ipv4Address, Name: name}" --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
}

# Convert the array of record sets into a table
$RecordSets | Format-Table -Property Zone, IPv4, Name

Response:

To get the desired output, you can make use of below modified script where I got the response successfully like this:
# Extract zones
$Zones = az network private-dns zone list -g "rgName" --query '[].{Name: name}' --output json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Initialize an empty array to store record sets
$RecordSets = @()

# Iterate over each zone
foreach ($zone in $Zones) {
    # Extract zone name
    $zoneName = $zone.Name

    # List record sets for the current zone and append to the array
    $RecordSets += az network private-dns record-set a list -g "rgName" -z $zoneName --query "[].{Zone: '$zoneName', IPv4: aRecords[0].ipv4Address, Name: name}" --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
}

# Convert the array of record sets into a table
$RecordSets | Format-Table -Property Zone, IPv4, Name

Response:


Nice.. Thank you for clarification! How can I sort the output based on the IPs
